# Is it possible to reinstall just the core macOS audio drivers on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, audio, drivers

My audio only works from the headphone jack and for a long time I thought it was a hardware issue. When I unplug from the headphone jack, I see the loudspeaker icon with the error-icon on the bottom.

But recently I discovered it’s most probably faulty OS audio-drivers because everything worked fine when booting my MacBook Pro from a friend’s hard drive.

So can I specifically reinstall just the audio-drivers. I couldn't find any info online so I’m afraid I would need to do a complete reinstall.

Comment: You'd have to do a complete re-isntall. But before you do that, perhaps try resetting the NVRAM (https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204063) and also fixing permissions (https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201560)

Answer (score 3):

Just reinstall macOS over your existing install. If you do that without telling it to erase your hard drive, it will do a “repair install” where all the OS pieces get reinstalled without losing your data.

However, it’s always wise to make sure you have a full, recent, **tested** backup before doing this kind of repair install, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to run disk utility and first aid. I also by chance tried Option+Command+P+R and got the frog sound :).

Got it here - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201560